# How to add a disk

Tags: filesystems, mount, centos-6

I would like to start to use a disk: /dev/sda (see bellow).

What do I need to do before I could copy files on it? (centos 6)

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1030.8 GB, 1030792151040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 125320 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00034e05

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        1306     9972736   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_root: 8095 MB, 8095006720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 984 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_swap: 2113 MB, 2113929216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 257 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

I'm not sure what I need to do. I guess I need to create and/or mount a filesystem? Maybe I also need to create a logical volume?

**EDIT** df -h does not show the disk

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_root
                      7.3G  4.5G  2.5G  65% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   64M  389M  15% /boot
```

Comment: Pls. post the output of `df -h`

Comment: Tried just mounting it, maybe read-only (ro) to start with, like `mount -v -o ro /dev/sda[1 or 2] somedirectory`? Is there anything important you want to keep on the drive, or is overwriting everything and starting clean OK? After reading the `df` edit,  `sda1` appears to be already mounted as your /boot partition, I'm not sure about `sda2` but it could be part of the LVM that contains your `/` and swap...?

Comment: Did not try to mount, but hey, thanks thanks for the hint. Mount resulted `mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'`. Now I think I will repost this question with more focus on 'how to mount a logical volume'. Thanks for your help